# Why doesn't my d3.js line chart work?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm currently learning d3.js, and as a task I am trying to build a line chart using a custom data source. For some reason, I can't get the line generator to work, and it seems like it can't create the d attribute for the path element. I don't seem to get any error messages either. Could someone please take a look?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    rect.bar {
        //fill: steelblue;
    }
.axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script>
data = [{
name:'A Negative',
data:[{x:1346103936,y:0.10252502},{x:1346190336,y:0.10838352},{x:1346276736,y:0.11182367},{x:1346363136,y:0.1469633},{x:1346449536,y:0.108044505},{x:1346535936,y:0.10141762},{x:1346622336,y:0.13505103},{x:1346708736,y:0.11661343},{x:1346795136,y:0.09985885},{x:1346881536,y:0.10367505},{x:1346967936,y:0.12067748},{x:1347054336,y:0.1329808},{x:1347140736,y:0.14677866},{x:1347227136,y:0.14087029},{x:1347313536,y:0.13160454},{x:1347399936,y:0.1313771},{x:1347486336,y:0.14144897},{x:1347572736,y:0.15051538},{x:1347659136,y:0.15604788},{x:1347745536,y:0.14364798},{x:1347831936,y:0.12961338},{x:1347918336,y:0.11450371},{x:1348004736,y:0.11712107},{x:1348091136,y:0.12876798},{x:1348177536,y:0.10429894},{x:1348263936,y:0.110398784},{x:1348350336,y:0.10483569},{x:1348436736,y:0.14220005},{x:1348523136,y:0.11701017},{x:1348609536,y:0.12221267},{x:1348696576,y:0.11133491}]},{
name:'A Positive',
data:[{x:1346105088,y:0.20869565},{x:1346191488,y:0.14895636},{x:1346277888,y:0.2819277},{x:1346364288,y:0.19342105},{x:1346450688,y:0.35833332},{x:1346537088,y:0.19473684},{x:1346623488,y:0.23015076},{x:1346709888,y:0.15840708},{x:1346796288,y:0.23293903},{x:1346882688,y:0.21885246},{x:1346969088,y:0.22707888},{x:1347055488,y:0.26593626},{x:1347141888,y:0.22822087},{x:1347228288,y:0.24236642},{x:1347314688,y:0.17460318},{x:1347401088,y:0.19075145},{x:1347487488,y:0.1594203},{x:1347573888,y:0.13432837},{x:1347660288,y:0.0},{x:1347746688,y:0.18100129},{x:1347833088,y:0.1605938},{x:1347919488,y:0.12987013},{x:1348005888,y:0.12683824},{x:1348092288,y:0.15542522},{x:1348178688,y:0.13584906},{x:1348265088,y:0.14351852},{x:1348351488,y:0.1322314},{x:1348437888,y:0.13709678},{x:1348524288,y:0.17438692},{x:1348610688,y:0.0},{x:1348700160,y:0.18169399}]},{
name:'A Uncertain',
data:[{x:1346104576,y:0.04397342},{x:1346190976,y:0.044665344},{x:1346277376,y:0.049782943},{x:1346363776,y:0.051038638},{x:1346450176,y:0.050243802},{x:1346536576,y:0.03118218},{x:1346622976,y:0.04424348},{x:1346709376,y:0.04498049},{x:1346795776,y:0.04105231},{x:1346882176,y:0.04970384},{x:1346968576,y:0.045589853},{x:1347054976,y:0.046243627},{x:1347141376,y:0.05226451},{x:1347227776,y:0.047814183},{x:1347314176,y:0.04413969},{x:1347400576,y:0.03914877},{x:1347486976,y:0.042237047},{x:1347573376,y:0.054126237},{x:1347659776,y:0.04697353},{x:1347746176,y:0.04476943},{x:1347832576,y:0.042521983},{x:1347918976,y:0.05310476},{x:1348005376,y:0.059566505},{x:1348091776,y:0.043783925},{x:1348178176,y:0.043761015},{x:1348264576,y:0.046513315},{x:1348350976,y:0.0384231},{x:1348437376,y:0.04024283},{x:1348523776,y:0.040613018},{x:1348610176,y:0.04732518},{x:1348696576,y:0.06337391}]},{
name:'A Positive',
data:[{x:1346104320,y:0.109645985},{x:1346190720,y:0.092952825},{x:1346277120,y:0.10988262},{x:1346363520,y:0.12258253},{x:1346449920,y:0.12162819},{x:1346536320,y:0.11145041},{x:1346622720,y:0.17937773},{x:1346709120,y:0.1605882},{x:1346795520,y:0.15555955},{x:1346881920,y:0.15066825},{x:1346968320,y:0.17311412},{x:1347054720,y:0.21528025},{x:1347141120,y:0.20169735},{x:1347227520,y:0.15779452},{x:1347313920,y:0.1469917},{x:1347400320,y:0.15995567},{x:1347486720,y:0.17675863},{x:1347573120,y:0.14658852},{x:1347659520,y:0.2049946},{x:1347745920,y:0.15699232},{x:1347832320,y:0.14301357},{x:1347918720,y:0.1457654},{x:1348005120,y:0.1532571},{x:1348091520,y:0.17817244},{x:1348177920,y:0.13126957},{x:1348264320,y:0.12135763},{x:1348350720,y:0.14930858},{x:1348437120,y:0.14171022},{x:1348523520,y:0.12027296},{x:1348609920,y:0.13843122},{x:1348696576,y:0.15421592}]},{
name:'A Uncertain',
data:[{x:1346103936,y:0.046369042},{x:1346190336,y:0.042160377},{x:1346276736,y:0.06631727},{x:1346363136,y:0.043078776},{x:1346449536,y:0.049522486},{x:1346535936,y:0.041241966},{x:1346622336,y:0.041665666},{x:1346708736,y:0.0461979},{x:1346795136,y:0.044713285},{x:1346881536,y:0.041361943},{x:1346967936,y:0.051421918},{x:1347054336,y:0.04684727},{x:1347140736,y:0.048165746},{x:1347227136,y:0.053684916},{x:1347313536,y:0.05550549},{x:1347399936,y:0.05435959},{x:1347486336,y:0.04710294},{x:1347572736,y:0.05433203},{x:1347659136,y:0.06015368},{x:1347745536,y:0.047590178},{x:1347831936,y:0.045565397},{x:1347918336,y:0.056516618},{x:1348004736,y:0.06080917},{x:1348091136,y:0.068452686},{x:1348177536,y:0.049881306},{x:1348263936,y:0.04221391},{x:1348350336,y:0.0484556},{x:1348436736,y:0.0402809},{x:1348523136,y:0.058744337},{x:1348609536,y:0.054147776},{x:1348696576,y:0.056016088}]},{
name:'A Negative',
data:[{x:1346104832,y:0.25386313},{x:1346191232,y:0.14606741},{x:1346277632,y:0.17222223},{x:1346364032,y:0.19863014},{x:1346450432,y:0.17857143},{x:1346536832,y:0.14606741},{x:1346623232,y:0.12448133},{x:1346709632,y:0.12931034},{x:1346796032,y:0.25714287},{x:1346882432,y:0.22222222},{x:1346968832,y:0.1764706},{x:1347055232,y:0.28846154},{x:1347141632,y:0.1826923},{x:1347228032,y:0.2236842},{x:1347314432,y:0.091836736},{x:1347400832,y:0.25},{x:1347487232,y:0.17567568},{x:1347573632,y:0.15384616},{x:1347660032,y:0.0},{x:1347746432,y:0.23584905},{x:1347832832,y:0.13718411},{x:1347919232,y:0.0},{x:1348005632,y:0.13533835},{x:1348092032,y:0.0},{x:1348178432,y:0.06315789},{x:1348264832,y:0.0},{x:1348351232,y:0.14457831},{x:1348437632,y:0.13253012},{x:1348524032,y:0.1},{x:1348610432,y:0.0},{x:1348700160,y:0.29826254}]}];


var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, "100%"])
        .domain(d3.extent(data[0].data, function(d) { return d.x }));

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
        .range([0, "100%"]);



var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x)})
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.y)})
        .interpolate("basis");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "500px");

var colors = d3.scale.category20().range();

var group = svg.selectAll("g").data(data);

group.enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i % colors.length]; })
        .attr("opacity", "0.5").attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", "2");

group.selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d) {return d.data})
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("class", "line");



</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple problems. The first is that the `width` and `height` attributes of SVG elements should be specified as unit-less numbers—always in pixels. This defines the coordinate space of the SVG element as well as its size on-screen. You can also set width and height *style properties* using px or percentages, but you should only do this *in addition* to setting the width and height attributes. The typical pattern is:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

You might also want to look at the [margin conventions example](http://bl.ocks.org/3019563) for more information.

The second thing I would change is to use this coordinate space to set the range of your scales, rather than using the percentage positioning:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(…)
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(…)
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Note that the y-scale's range is inverted, so that y-0 is at the bottom of the chart rather than the default top. Again, see the conventions example for details.

Lastly, it looks like your x-values are seconds since UNIX epoch, so I would recommend converting your data to Date objects and then using a d3.time.scale. This makes it much easier to add an x-axis with date labels in the future. You can convert to dates as a preprocessing step like so:

```
data.forEach(function(series) {
  series.data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = new Date(d.x * 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It was much needed. :)